# spring-boot No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc' available

Tags: spring-boot

Dears,
I am new to spring boot, I downloaded the getting started project from "https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/"
but when I tried to run it as it's I got the following exception

No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc' available

please advise

Answer (score 0):

Dears,

it seems there were some problem in my local maven repository
I cleaned my local maven spring repository and let the build to download it again and everything went fine